# cannot get controller instance variable with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have simple controller:

```
class CreditLogsController < BaseController

  def show
    @account = Account.find_by_email(Base64.urlsafe_decode64(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

and here is the spec for it:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe CreditLogsController, type: :controller do

  describe 'GET #show' do
    it 'responds with 200' do
      create(:account)

      get :show, params: {id: Base64.urlsafe_encode64('tes1@test.com')}, format: :html
      puts "############# #{controller.instance_variable_get(:account)}"
      expect(assigns(:account)).to eql('tes1@test.com')
    end
  end

end
```

The problems is that `account` in spec is always `nil`, in coverage file code from controller which assigns value to `@account` is showed as not covered and `controller.instance_variable_get(:account)` raises an error:

> `account' is not allowed as an instance variable name.

I have similar code in other spec and is working ok, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use FactoryGirl to create account? you are comparing an object `@account` with a string `'tes1@test.com'`? It should be `expect(assigns(:account).email).to eql('tes1@test.com')`

Comment: seems that the code pointer hasn't reach the show action method

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicates, that's the wrong name for an instance variable. They must start with `@`, and so do the symbols and strings describing them.

You must use:

```
controller.instance_variable_get(:@account)
```

or

```
controller.instance_variable_get('@account')
```

The rest of your test (`expect(assigns(:account))...`) will not be reached, as `instance_variable_get(:account)` will raise a `NameError` exception.

Comment: if I use controller.instance_variable_get(:@account) I have the same problem, value is nil

Comment: @maki So your `find_by_email` isn't working, and I can't see any reason why it would. Do some debugging, drop a `binding.pry` in there. We can't fix everything for you.

Comment: you are not right, the problem is not in find_by_email, for example if I just assign some value @account = "test" it's still nil in spec